# Update duplicate column values in PostgreSQL adding a number at end

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to update the duplicate usernames in my PostgreSQL database by adding a number at the end of the duplicates.
curently my users table is as follows:

```
| user_id | username |
|---------|----------|
| 1       | mike     |
| 2       | mike     |
| 3       | susan    |
| 4       | susan    |
| 5       | susan    |
| 6       | joe      |
```

And the expected result is:

```
| user_id | username |
|---------|----------|
| 1       | mike     |
| 2       | mike2    |
| 3       | susan    |
| 4       | susan2   |
| 5       | susan3   |
| 6       | joe      |
```

I've been trying to use some expressions found here in StackOverflow but i keep getting a SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update from a sub-query:

```
update users
   set username = concat(t.username, t.rn)
from (
  select user_id, username, 
         row_number(*) over (partition by username order by user_id) as rn
  from users
) t
where t.user_id = users.user_id
  and t.rn > 1;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=258784c75f649152257280c15fac164d)